# What's the best way of attaching playframework sources for debugging in Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, playframework

I am implementing a set of backend RESTful services using the [PlayFramework](https://www.playframework.com/) (v2.3.8) and its plugin [play-authenticate](https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate/) (v0.6.8), and would like to find an easier way of attaching their source code in eclipse for debugging (both of playframework and of whatever other dependency I use).

To download sources, I am adding **withSources()** both to the **build.sbt** (for dependencies) and to **plugin.sbt** (for the sbt play plugin), however this doesn't bring me all the source code of playframework (i.e., I still need to add the source code of each module of the framework one by one - see the build.sbt example below), and it does not include them automatically on the classpath when I use **activator eclipse**, which means I have to manually "Attach source" for each compiled class the debugger doesn't find in the classpath.

**Is there any way of making this process easier, automatically adding all source code jars to the project's classpath, and making eclipse to automatically attach these sources when debugging?**

**my build.sbt**

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache,
  javaWs, 
  "com.feth" %% "play-authenticate" % "0.6.8" withSources(), 
  "com.typesafe.play" % "play_2.11" % "2.3.7" withSources(), // how to download all play-framework module source code at once? 
  "com.typesafe.play" % "play-java_2.11" % "2.3.8" withSources(), // how to download all play-framework module source code at once?  
  "org.springframework" % "spring-context" % "4.0.3.RELEASE" withSources() // how to download all dependencies source code at once? 
)
```

**my plugins.sbt**

```
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

// The Play plugin
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.3.8" withSources() withJavadoc())

// web plugins
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-coffeescript" % "1.0.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-less" % "1.0.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-jshint" % "1.0.1")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.1")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.0.0")    
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-mocha" % "1.0.0")
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to set flag. activator eclipse with-source=true according to Documentation https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/IDE

Comment: That's a good catch. Not sure how I missed that option. Will test it and let you know if it actually works

Comment: Long time has passed, but to be fair, I have to confirm that your answer worked :-)